# putting android {} block into project extension in kotlin dsl build.gradle.kts

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to put android {} block in to project.myextension tih dependencies altogether.

How can I do this?

```
fun Project.androidUIDep(){
    apply(plugin = "com.android.application")
    apply(plugin = "kotlin-android")


    android{} ?? 
dependencies {
        "implementation"(project(":domain"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.extensions.configure<ApplicationExtension>("android") { }
```

or

```
this.extensions.configure<LibraryExtension>("android") { }
```